# I'm using a SingleChildScrollView to display text - works in emulator but not in release on Google Play

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an alert popup using rflutter_alert, that contains a text widget (and Ok button). The text is wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView to scroll the text vertically.

This works with no issues when in debug mode - either with the emulator or on my android phone. But the release version after being approved on Google Play, does not work. The text area is one long grey box with no text. Images as follows.

My other rflutter_alerts (without a scrollable view) work fine in release mode.

Is there a user permission required for release for scrolling views? Or some other difference between test and release?

[image]

[image]

```
// Alert to display roster message
_onAlertShowRosterNotes(context, String rosterMsg) {
  var alertStyle = AlertStyle(
    isCloseButton: false,
  );
  Alert(
    context: context,
    style: alertStyle,
    title: 'Roster Message',
    content: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.0, 3.0, 6.0, 3.0),
          height: 280.0,
          width: 230,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: kMainColor,
            width: 0.5,
          ),
          ),
          child: Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Text(rosterMsg,
                style: TextStyle(
                color: kBodyText,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    buttons: [
      DialogButton(
        child: Text('OK', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
        color: kMainColor,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, false);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the Expanded widget. Once I removed this, the problem went away.